# Trouble connecting to Google Could SQL database (no suitable driver found....)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have searched many topics but none of them could help me. Here's my situation:

- App in the app engine (flexible)
- Second generation MySQL database
- Both exist in the same project

Dependencies in the POM.xml:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.39</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.48</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Java code:

```
    String jdbcUrl = String.format(
            "jdbc:mysql://google/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory",
            "MyTable",
            "xxxx:us-central1:xxxx");

    con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, "root", "xxxxxx");
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES");
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        ...
    }
```

I am getting the following error when I have deployed the app to the cloud using:

```
mvn appengine:update

No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://google/MyTable?cloudSqlInstance=xxxx:us-central1:xxxx&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
```

As far as I understand I don't need the use-google-connector-j in my appengine-web.xml

Anyone have any clues? I have been struggling with this for almost two days now...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I  agree, you don't need to enable connector if you are connecting to mysql locally. You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/tree/master/examples/mysql/compute-engine) sample.